# How to import android apk

Tags: android

I have been sent an android app to test. I saved the apk to my desktop, but now I don't know what else to do. How do I import it into androis studio? I know this is a very basic question but please be detailed, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are supposed to test, but if you were sent an apk file, then you should move it over to your android device and install it. You can't edit an apk file in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your android device (or start an emulator), go to the command prompt, change directory to where the apk is, and enter `adb install apkname`

Comment: do i create a new blank project first and run emulator on that

Comment: No, you just follow the instructions in the answers from me and user3468596.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please follow the below steps to install apk file.
1.First run the emulator.
2. open the  sdk specified path and find the platform tools folder.then copy the apk file and store it inside the  platform-tools folder.(G:android-sdks\platform-tools).
3.open the command prompt and change the directory to android-sdks/platform tools.
4.enter the command : adb install apkfile name.
5.if you are getting success in command prompt the apk was sucessfully installed in your emulator..
```